# Event catcher, for user hiding keyboard with back button

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an app that uses the keyboard, when the keyboard is up if the user presses back button the keyboard dissappears, however I would like to change one or two other things while it changes, so I need an event listener.

I tried

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed()
```

However this doesnt seem to catch the backbutton while the keyboard is up, if the user presses back twice, then this catches the second click only

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top) out. And next time please do a little research before posting a quesiton.

Comment: Not really the same question, my main point is to find out when back button is pressed, not a general catch all for finding whether the keyboard is there or not

Comment: As far as I am aware you cannot do that. However there might be a workaround for a limited number of `EditText`s. Check [onKeyPreIme](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onKeyPreIme). You can use keycode to compare with `KeyEvent.KeyCode_Back`. But how are you going to get all the events of all the `EditText`s to the `MainActiivty` is beyond me.

Comment: So there is no way to simple fire off an event of backbutton is pressed when keyboard is up?

Comment: But you could call your `MainActivity.onBackPressed()` from all the events.

Comment: No direct way at least. But you could gather all the events (as suggested earlier) in `onBackPressed()` of your `MainActivity` and handle it there.

Answer (score 0):

Register this on your root view to detect keyboard appearance/disappearance :

```
root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
 public void onGlobalLayout(){
       int heightDiff = root.getRootView().getHeight()- root.getHeight();
       /*If height difference is more then 150, consider keyboard as visible. -150 for disappearing */ 

    }
```

});

Also, make sure to use adjustResize for keyboard.